# var "template compile dir" not set properly

Tags: settings, cv

An "cv core:check-req" after a fresh install of Drupal 9 and CiviCRM 5.60 showed

> The template compile dir
> ".../home//public_html/web/web/sites/default/files/civ/templates_c"
> can be created.

but there is no path ".../files/civ"
and templates_c exists in path

> .../public_html/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c

Should I point "template compile dir" to this location?

> cv core:check-req
> --templateCompilePathWritable=
> "/public_html/web/sites/default/files/civicrm"

What happens when "template compile dir" is not properly set?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would happen on a fresh install but check what template compile dir is set to in civicrm.settings.php

Comment: @Demerit, thks for reply.
In civicrm.settings.php:

if (!defined('CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR')) {
  define( 'CIVICRM_TEMPLATE_COMPILEDIR', '/home/<account>/public_html/web/sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c');
}

Comment: That looks right. I don't know where else the "civ" would be coming from.